# Date difference between two dates (Changing From Minutes To Hours etc.)

Tags: php

I am trying to make a website for a server, where there is coded so it updated a database everytime someone leaves the server, let's say I left the server at 13.03.14 15:50 and that updates to the database, and I want to print that to the website, just instead of saying Last Seen: 13.03.14 15:50, it will say:

Last Seen: 1 Minute Ago

Until it's been 1 hour then it's:

Last Seen: 1 Hour Ago

I think you know what I mean, so I want that and all the way until:

Last Seen: Over a year ago

Someone think they can help?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Search this site. This has been asked a lot.

Comment: @JohnConde I know, I have been searching for hours now, but the thing is, none of the questions and answers I've found, has helped me...

Comment: Just convert both dates to timestamps with strtotime, then substract divide by 3600 and floor.